# How to add MessageID in SOAP request using Axis2 and Rampart

Tags: xml, web-services, soap, apache-axis, rampart

I am trying to build a client application that consume external server application using `Axis2` and `rampat 1.6`.

Everything seems to be fine when checking SOAP request, since SOAP get encrypted and signed as expected. Following is the policy.xml file used for that purpose:

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="MyPolicy"
    xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
    xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy"
    xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy"
    xmlns:wsam="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" 
    xmlns:wst="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/oasis-wss-saml-token-profile-1.0#SAMLAssertionID">
<wsp:ExactlyOne>
    <wsp:All>
        <sp:SignedSupportingTokens xmlns:sp="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
            <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:UsernameToken sp:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient" />
            </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:SignedSupportingTokens>
        <sp:SymmetricBinding>
            <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:ProtectionToken>
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:X509Token sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/Never">
                            <wsp:Policy>
                                <sp:RequireIssuerSerialReference/>
                                <sp:WssX509V3Token10/>
                            </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:X509Token>
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:ProtectionToken>

                <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:Basic128/>
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                <sp:IncludeTimestamp/>
                <sp:Layout>
                    <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:Strict/>
                    </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:Layout>
                <sp:OnlySignEntireHeadersAndBody/>
            </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:SymmetricBinding>
        <sp:EncryptedParts>
            <sp:Body />
        </sp:EncryptedParts>
        <sp:SignedParts>
            <sp:Body/>
            <sp:Header Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" Name="ReplyTo"/>
            <sp:Header Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" Name="To"/>
            <sp:Header Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" Name="From"/>
            <sp:Header Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702" Name="AckRequested"/>
            <sp:Header Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702" Name="CreateSequence"/>
            <sp:Header Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702" Name="Sequence"/>
            <sp:Header Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" Name="MessageID"/>
            <sp:Header Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" Name="FaultTo"/>
            <sp:Header Namespace="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-rx/wsrm/200702" Name="SequenceAcknowledgement"/>
            <sp:Header Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" Name="Action"/>
            <sp:Header Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" Name="RelatesTo"/>
        </sp:SignedParts>
        <sp:Wss11>
            <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:MustSupportRefEncryptedKey/>
                <sp:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial/>
                <sp:MustSupportRefThumbprint/>
            </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:Wss11>
        <ramp:RampartConfig xmlns:ramp="http://ws.apache.org/rampart/policy">
            <ramp:userCertAlias>mySignAlias</ramp:userCertAlias>
            <ramp:encryptionUser>myEncryptAlias</ramp:encryptionUser>
            <ramp:user>myUser</ramp:user>
            <ramp:passwordCallbackClass>myPackage.PasswordCallBackHandler</ramp:passwordCallbackClass>
            <ramp:encryptionCypto>
                <ramp:crypto provider="org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin">
                    <ramp:property name="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type">JKS</ramp:property>
                    <ramp:property name="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.file">[path goes here]/clientTrustStore.jks</ramp:property>
                    <ramp:property name="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password">changeit</ramp:property>
                </ramp:crypto>
            </ramp:encryptionCypto>

            <ramp:signatureCrypto>
                <ramp:crypto provider="org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin">
                    <ramp:property name="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type">JKS</ramp:property>
                    <ramp:property name="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.file">[path goes here]/clientKeyStore.jks</ramp:property>
                    <ramp:property name="org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password">changeit</ramp:property>
                </ramp:crypto>
            </ramp:signatureCrypto>
        </ramp:RampartConfig>

    </wsp:All>
</wsp:ExactlyOne>
```

But I am getting the following axis fault while calling external server application:

```
SEVERE: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: com.sun.xml.wss.XWSSecurityException: Policy verification error:Missing target MessageID for Signature
at org.apache.axis2.util.Utils.getInboundFaultFromMessageContext(Utils.java:531)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:375)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:421)
at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:229)
at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:165)
```

The error is self descriptive, SOAP request is missing `MessageID` tag in SOAP header. I tired to find out how to add mentioned tag but no luck; I found out how to add custom SOAP header in this link [adding authentication header to client stub axis2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12997316/adding-authentification-header-to-client-stub-axis2/13638880#13638880)

But I want to avoid that since I am using `PasswordCallBackHandler` to add authentication proprieties.

Is there any way to add the `MessageID` automatically within SOAP header ? Further, there is similar tags like `Action` , `ReplyTo` ,`To` , and `From` how to add them to SOAP header ?

**-- UPDATE:**

From the auto generated java files using `Axis2` tool  - *see [Apache Axis2 User's Guide - Creating Clients](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/userguide-creatingclients.html) to know how stub files has been generated* - I went to the API method in the auto generated Java class `ServiceStub`. There is a message contxet is created to send SOAP request like the follwoing:

```
 // create a message context
_messageContext = new org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext();
```

I used the object `_messageContext` to set the message ID as follow:

```
_messageContext.setMessageID("TEST_123456");
```

Further, I ran application on debug mode and I can see that `TEST_123456` has been added to the SOAP request as `MessageID` and the server is using the same `MessageID` in its response. But still I am getting this wired error `Policy verification error:Missing target MessageID for Signature`

It is confusing me how server said he is missing`MessageID` although it is appearing in SOAP request and response which coming from the server only !

Is this has any thing to do with the auto signature proccess ? But even so,  `MessageID` is already added in the `SignedParts` from policy file what else could be done to over come this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add all properties like Message,Action,To and Other Properties in `Stub::ServiceClient::Options`.

```
ServiceClient client = serviceStub._getServiceClient();
Options options = client.getOptions();
options.setAction(action);
options.setTo(new EndpointReference(referenceURL));
options.setMessageId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
```

[Sample Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILSID.png)